# Overriding Python Mechanize.Browser.open() method

Tags: python, mechanize-python

The following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                       

import mechanize

class MechanizeSubclass(mechanize.Browser):
    def __init__(self,
                 factory=None,
                 history=None,
                 request_class=None,
                ):
        mechanize.Browser.__init__(self, factory, history, request_class)

    def open(self, url, data=None,
             timeout=mechanize._sockettimeout._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
        mechanize.Browser.open(self, url, data, timeout=timeout)

subclass = MechanizeSubclass()
subclass.open('https://uncjobs.northcarolina.edu/applicants/jsp/shared/Welcome_css.jsp')
print subclass.response().read()
```

generates the error

```
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 302: Moved Temporarily
```

I looked at the mechanize code and the Browser.open() method is defined as:

```
    def open(self, url, data=None,
         timeout=_sockettimeout._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
```

and if I change the open() method in my subclass to match this:

```
class MechanizeSubclass(mechanize.Browser):
    ...
    def open(self, url, data=None,
         timeout=mechanize._sockettimeout._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
        return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
```

then it works fine. But I still don't really understand why the first definition using mechanize.Browser.open(self, url, data, timeout=timeout) doesn't work. Shouldn't they be equivalent? This is with python 2.6 with mechanize 0.2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between the first code snippet and the other two is that the `open`method is not returning anything (which in Python isthe same as returning the `None` object).

That is, whatever code is calling the `open`method expects to have the object returned by `_mech_open`. Your first method just returns nothing.

If you simply change the first implementation to:

```
class MechanizeSubclass(mechanize.Browser):
    ...
    def open(self, url, data=None,
             timeout=mechanize._sockettimeout._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
        return mechanize.Browser.open(self, url, data, timeout=timeout)
```

You should not have this problem.